# Google Tag Manager: Preview Mode Broken

Tags: google-tag-manager

I'm able to preview in Google Tag Manager, however none of the tags are firing. When I opened up the console, I see the following error

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: Rj is not defined
    at fk (www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id=GTM-WT6PRS:137)
    at ik (www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id=GTM-WT6PRS:141)
    at eg (www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id=GTM-WT6PRS:165)
    at og (www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id=GTM-WT6PRS:59)
    at pg (www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id=GTM-WT6PRS:60)
```

What could be going wrong here?

Comment: I have having the same issue. It seems Google has updated GTM which is causing the issue to happen. Also its just impacting the debug mode as I am seeing other tags firing correctly without the debug mode. Have to wait till Google fix the issue.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was a bug from Google's end for some time. Google was pushing new changes. More history can by found here https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/tag-manager/kMh-BsC4BUM;context-place=forum/tag-manager

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: Refresh... seems issue has been resolved!

Having the same issue. I'm guessing, but i think there was an update done on googles side that might contain a bug. Notice that the 'publish' button it is now a 'submit' button. If this is the case hopefully Google will deploy a fix soon.

Comment: I am also having the same issue. I noticed that when i removed all of the Universal Analytics Tag's Field to Set, and refresh the preview, it will work just fine.

Comment: Tried removing my 'fields to set', didn't make a difference.